# How replace Ember.ObjectController with Ember.Controller

Tags: ember.js

An application I'm currently working on uses an `Ember.ArrayController` to load a couple of `place` models. To obtain different behavior for different model types I used the `lookupItemController` like this:

**PlacesController**

```
lookupItemController: function(object) {
  if(object.get('isNew')) {
    return "places.new";
  } else {
    return "places.index";
  }
}
```

**PlacesNewController**

```
needs: ['places']

isDraggable: Ember.computed.alias('isCloseEnough')

isCloseEnough: false
isZoomMax: false
isMarkerAdded: false

...
```

**PlacesIndexController**

```
needs: 'places',
isDraggable: false,
modelBinding: 'places.model'

...
```

But now the `Ember.ObjectController` is deprecated. My question is therefor: how can I get the same behavior using the `Ember.Controller`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use them absolutely the same as before. The only difference is that you won't be able to proxy for model's properties.

So if you used to have `{{a.b.c}}` reaching into your `model.a.b.c` through the controller, now you have to do one of the following:

1) Change the property lookup path in your template to `{{model.a.b.c}}`

2) In your controller (what used to be ObjectController), add something like this:

```
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    a: Ember.computed.alias('model.a'),
    //...
});
```